# "This webpage has a redirect loop"

Tags: bug

Sometimes when I load CrossValidated, I get an error that the page has a redirect loop.  I can always resolve this by going to meta.stats.stackexchange.com and then reloading stats.stackexchange.com.  Sometimes the problem is reversed - the redirect loop is on meta.stats.se and can be fixed by going to stats.se.

I've only experienced in on CrossValidated - not on SO or any of the other SE sites I drop in on occasionally.  It also only happens at work, so it's most likely a consequence of some weird little bit of code unique to this site interacting with my organization's web security.

I don't expect this to be fixed for my sake - I can't even reproduce it reliably - but I thought I'd put my experience down for the record.

#### TLDR:

- Redirect loop prevents pages from loading
- Fixed by loading meta.stats.se if stats.se is redirecting, and vice versa
- Only at work
- Only on stats.stackexchange.com and meta.stats.stackexchange.com
- Chrome 20.0.1132.57 m
- Windows XP Pro, Version 2002, SP 3

Here's the Chrome error:

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at http://stats.stackexchange.com/ has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Learn more about this problem.
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.
```

Clearing cookies does fix it, but only temporarily.

Comment: Interesting. I have not experienced this. I have had to kill the browser on a few occasions because something with the scripting gets screwed up. Does the "m" in the Chrome version indicate "Microsoft"? If not, you might add the OS information to this. :)

Comment: @cardinal Good suggestion, thanks! I'm sure it's something along those lines with the scripting - just peculiar that it only happens on this particular SE site.

Comment: This does not happen with Firefox.